# How to pass a component as a prop from React Router?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have a Meteor/React application with the following React Router set up:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/app" component={AppWrapperContainer} >
        ...
        <Route path="/app/somepath" component={SomeComponentContainer} />
        ...
    </Route>
</Router>
```

`SomeComponentContainer` is a container component that collects data from MongoDB and passes it to `SomeComponent` (not shown above). I need to pass `SomeComponentContainer` into a generic wrapper component, lets call it `GenericWrapper`, such that it looks like this:

```
<GenericWrapper component={SomeComponentContainer} />
```

and `GenericWrapper` will render whatever component is passed to it:

```
export default class GenericWrapper extends Component {
    ...
    render(){
        return (
            <{this.props.component} {...props} />
        );
    }
}
```

1) How is this written at the React Router level?
2) How is this written for `GenericWrapper` to accept the component?

Comment: How about this? Make `GenericWrapper` as a Higher order function component and pass `SomeComponentContainer` as an argument.

Comment: er.. what does that look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for a late reply, and I couldn't update it in the comments :)

The idea is roughly as follows,

Define a Higher order component for GenericWrapper as below,

```
export function GenericWrapper(Component) {
    class GenericWrapperComponent extends React.Component {
     ....
    }
}
```

and in router,

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/app" component={AppWrapperContainer} >
        ...
        <Route path="/app/somepath" component=GenericWrapper(SomeComponentContainer) />
        ...
    </Route>
</Router>
```